# Http 304 & Cache-Control: no-cache

Tags: html, http, http-headers

I'm seeing the below response from some calls to a webserver:

**Initial call:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2012 05:46:49 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 78
Content-Encoding: gzip
Etag: "pv2052dae8634d971149a927231e3ceddf"
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-PvInfo: [S10202.C6191.A6057.RA6008.G182D.U3FAE8760].[OT/plaintext.OG/documents]
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=l9pLPT5J1tpgK19Fq2qlT0F15ryByWDLgVLz16ffWPm4qQp6nzzx!-518520380; path=/; HttpOnly
DST=rd319o00000000000000000000ffffac16018bo8200; path=/
Connection: close
```

**Subsequent calls:**

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2012 05:48:43 GMT
Connection: close
Etag: "pv2052dae8634d971149a927231e3ceddf"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

What I'm unclear about is that both calls return a `Cache-Control: no-cache` directive to the browser.

However, the second call also returns a `304 Not Modified`.

Where does the server expect the page to serve the data from, given that it's been instructed not to cache the earlier response?

Interestingly, I **do** see the response served in the browser, so the browser appears to have cached the response, despite the no-cache directive.  Why?

Comment: Please post request header for first request and subsequent request.You will see what browser is sending to webserver.Cache-Control: no-cache means that webserver instruct browser to not cache response body.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A [response with `Cache-Control: no-cache`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9.1) does not mean that the response must not be stored at the client at all, instead it means:

> If the no-cache directive does not specify a field-name, then a
> cache MUST NOT use the response to satisfy a subsequent request
> without successful revalidation with the origin server. This
> allows an origin server to prevent caching even by caches that
> have been configured to return stale responses to client requests.

So the client is allowed to store the response in the local cache but it needs to revalidate the response by the origin server. If the server says that the response stored in the client’s cache is still valid (i. e. 304 response), the client is allowed to use the stored response to satisfy the request.

Comment: Nice explanation.  How do I tell the server _not_ to return the Cache-Control directive?  IE I don't want the client to re-validate against the server?

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy set 'cache-control: max-age' for some time, alternatively use the 'immutable' directive if you expect the file to never change.

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy, the browser revalidates because it received the `ETag: ...` and `Last-Modified: ...` headers. Without those, it would not be capable to revalidate and instead would have to do a full `GET`. If you're in control of the client, just don't send the corresponding headers (`If-None-Match: ...` and `If-Modified-Since: ...`). If you're in control of the server, do not send the `ETag: ...` and `Last-Modified: ...` or ignore the incoming `If-...` (but that can be tricky if you have CDN and other such intermediate caches).