# How do caches validate the response when using `Cache-Control: no-cache`?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control, request-headers

Quote from [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#no-cache_2):

> #### `no-cache`
>
> The `no-cache` request directive asks caches to validate the response with the origin server before reuse.
>
> ```
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> ```
>
> `no-cache` allows clients to request the most up-to-date response even if the cache has a fresh response.

My understanding is that when using `no-cache`, the caches validate the response's time with the system time, if it's not the same, the clients will then request the latest response, is that correct?

If not, then how do caches validate the response when using `Cache-Control: no-cache`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Http 304 & Cache-Control: no-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876263/http-304-cache-control-no-cache)

Comment: This is a very general question, that's already been covered by several answers. See [RFC 7234, 4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.3) ("This process is known as "validating" or "revalidating" the stored response.") for the spec, or other more specific questions to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Joe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70469152/how-do-caches-validate-the-response-when-using-cache-control-no-cache/70491403#comment124607148_70469152), quoting from [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.3):

> **Validation**
>
> When a cache has one or more stored responses for a requested URI,
> but cannot serve any of them (e.g., because they are not fresh, or
> one cannot be selected; see Section 4.1), it can use the conditional
> request mechanism [RFC7232] in the forwarded request to give the next
> inbound server an opportunity to select a valid stored response to
> use, updating the stored metadata in the process, or to replace the
> stored response(s) with a new response. This process is known as
> "validating" or "revalidating" the stored response.